# Disable alert when sending task but not keeping a copy

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm assigning an Outlook task via Excel. As I have not saved a copy of the task an alert shows saying that the task won't be saved and asking if I want to send it anyway.

I've been using Sendkeys (I know, it's not a good way). It's working on my computer but not on the computers of some of my colleagues.

Would it be possible to deactivate those alerts?

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub SendMail(dest As String, Echeance As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim nom As String
Dim compte As Integer
Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient
Set myOlApp = New Outlook.Application

For i = 1 To myOlApp.Session.Folders.Count
    If myOlApp.Session.Folders.Item(i) = "_F_VTG-LBA ALCG-RAVEVAC" Then
        compte = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i


Set myItem = myOlApp.Session.Folders.Item(compte).Items.Add(olTaskItem)

myItem.Assign
Set myDelegate = myItem.Recipients.Add(dest)

myDelegate.Resolve
If myDelegate.Resolved Then
    myItem.Subject = Task.titre
    myItem.Body = Task.Mess
    myItem.DueDate = Echeance

    myItem.StartDate = Now
    myItem.ReminderTime = True 'Rappel
    myItem.Display
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    myItem.Send

'Or

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Application.SendKeys "^~" 'presses send as a send key
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    SendKeys "TAB", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
    i = 0
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You have 'Application.DisplayAlerts = False' twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the task in your own list then assign the normal way then delete.

```
myItem.Display ' Do not uncheck the box
myItem.Send
myItem.Delete
```